# Is it possible in Views to get parent term of parent term all the way up a tree

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm at my wits end on this. Here's my situation:

1. I have a content type which references a Vocabulary of geographical areas which actually has 6 levels ("Island Chain > Region > Province > City > District > Precinct").
2. I've used Hierarchical Select to control data entry, and set it so that the entire lineage is kept in each attached node - the node should be attached at the precinct level.

Now, what I want to do is to create a View which allows me to display a table of nodes, grouped by geographical area, and at the same time allow the user to select the geographical area he wishes to display (preferably at any level in the hierarchy).

I've already done something like this using a View by Taxonomy formatted as a table, attaching the content, and then displaying in each table row the node data, the term, and the parent term. However, this only seems to work for two levels (ie a Vocabulary where there is only a parent/child relationship), and I'm stuck on displaying the bottom level, then its parent, then its parent again, all the way up to the top and all in the same row so that I don't get duplicate lines and can group/aggregate data at all these different levels.

By the way, it seems that the Hierarchical Select Views module still does not work for D7 - or at least, I can't find out how to display it.

Answer (score 0):

use [Client-side hierarchical select"](https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs) module.

1)Force selection of deepest level (If checked the user will be forced to select terms from the deepest level.)

2)Parent (Allows to select a parent term to use only a subtree of a vocabulary for this field.)

3)Labels per hierarchy-level

Comment: That looks useful for the selection - but I can't see how it helps me with the grouping of the results in Views, which is my vital issue